# Pytorch:Apply cross entropy loss with custom weight map

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am solving multi-class segmentation problem using u-net architecture in pytorch.
As specified in [U-NET](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) paper, I am trying to implement custom weight maps to counter class imbalances.

Below is the opertion which I want to apply - 
[image]

Also, I reduced the `batch_size=1` so that I can remove that dimension while passing it to `precompute_to_masks` function.
I tried the below approach-

```
def precompute_for_image(masks):
    masks = masks.cpu()
    cls = masks.unique()
    res = torch.stack([torch.where(masks==cls_val, torch.tensor(1), torch.tensor(0)) for cls_val in cls])
    return res

def train(n_epochs, loaders, model, optimizer, criterion, use_cuda, save_path):

        ###################
        # train the model #
        ###################
        model.train()
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(final_train_loader):
            # move to GPU
            if use_cuda:
                data, target = data.cuda(), target.cuda()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(data)
            temp_target = precompute_for_image(target)
            w = weight_map(temp_target)
            loss = criterion(output,target)
            loss = w*loss
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            train_loss = train_loss + ((1 / (batch_idx + 1)) * (loss.data - train_loss))

    return model
```

where weight_map is the function to calculate weight mask which I got from [here](https://jaidevd.github.io/posts/weighted-loss-functions-for-instance-segmentation/)
The issue, I am facing is I am getting `memory error` when I apply the following method. 
I am using 61gb RAM and Tesla V100 GPU.
I really think I am applying it in incorrect way.
How to do it?

I am omitting the non-essential details from the training loop.
Below is my `weight_map` function:

```
from skimage.segmentation import find_boundaries

w0 = 10
sigma = 5

def make_weight_map(masks):
    """
    Generate the weight maps as specified in the UNet paper
    for a set of binary masks.

    Parameters
    ----------
    masks: array-like
        A 3D array of shape (n_masks, image_height, image_width),
        where each slice of the matrix along the 0th axis represents one binary mask.

    Returns
    -------
    array-like
        A 2D array of shape (image_height, image_width)

    """
    nrows, ncols = masks.shape[1:]
    masks = (masks > 0).astype(int)
    distMap = np.zeros((nrows * ncols, masks.shape[0]))
    X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(nrows), np.arange(ncols))
    X1, Y1 = np.c_[X1.ravel(), Y1.ravel()].T
    for i, mask in enumerate(masks):
        # find the boundary of each mask,
        # compute the distance of each pixel from this boundary
        bounds = find_boundaries(mask, mode='inner')
        X2, Y2 = np.nonzero(bounds)
        xSum = (X2.reshape(-1, 1) - X1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
        ySum = (Y2.reshape(-1, 1) - Y1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
        distMap[:, i] = np.sqrt(xSum + ySum).min(axis=0)
    ix = np.arange(distMap.shape[0])
    if distMap.shape[1] == 1:
        d1 = distMap.ravel()
        border_loss_map = w0 * np.exp((-1 * (d1) ** 2) / (2 * (sigma ** 2)))
    else:
        if distMap.shape[1] == 2:
            d1_ix, d2_ix = np.argpartition(distMap, 1, axis=1)[:, :2].T
        else:
            d1_ix, d2_ix = np.argpartition(distMap, 2, axis=1)[:, :2].T
        d1 = distMap[ix, d1_ix]
        d2 = distMap[ix, d2_ix]
        border_loss_map = w0 * np.exp((-1 * (d1 + d2) ** 2) / (2 * (sigma ** 2)))
    xBLoss = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))
    xBLoss[X1, Y1] = border_loss_map
    # class weight map
    loss = np.zeros((nrows, ncols))
    w_1 = 1 - masks.sum() / loss.size
    w_0 = 1 - w_1
    loss[masks.sum(0) == 1] = w_1
    loss[masks.sum(0) == 0] = w_0
    ZZ = xBLoss + loss
    return ZZ
```

Traceback of the error-

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-f0a595b8de7e> in <module>
      1 # train the model
      2 model_scratch = train(20, final_train_loader, unet, optimizer, 
----> 3                       criterion, train_on_gpu, 'model_scratch.pt')

<ipython-input-29-b481b4f3120e> in train(n_epochs, loaders, model, optimizer, criterion, use_cuda, save_path)
     24             loss = criterion(output,target)
     25             target.requires_grad = False
---> 26             w = make_weight_map(target)
     27             loss = W*loss
     28             loss.backward()

<ipython-input-5-e75a6281476f> in make_weight_map(masks)
     33         X2, Y2 = np.nonzero(bounds)
     34         xSum = (X2.reshape(-1, 1) - X1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
---> 35         ySum = (Y2.reshape(-1, 1) - Y1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
     36         distMap[:, i] = np.sqrt(xSum + ySum).min(axis=0)
     37     ix = np.arange(distMap.shape[0])

MemoryError:
```

Comment: try setting `target.requires_grad = False` before computing weight map.

Comment: still getting he same error

Comment: The crossentropy loss in pytorch already supports a weighted version. You probably want to use `loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(output, target, w)`. I'm guessing `w` is a vector and `loss` is a scalar in your example. After muliplying by `w` you are left with a vector, and you can't back propagate a vector using `.backward()`.

Comment: did you try reducing the batch size? in which line did you get the memory error? your post does not provide enough information.

Comment: @jodag I call `torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(output, target, w)` outside the training loop and w is the function of `target` then I really don't know how to call it outside the training loop

Comment: @WasiAhmad Yes, I reduced the batch size from 5 to 1, still the same error. I also edited the traceback to the question

Comment: @Mark No, you should call `nn.functional.cross_entropy` inside the training loop, in place of `criterion` and `w*loss`. Also your code is failing in a function `make_weight_map` which isn't included in the code you posted. If you could post a minimal, *complete*, verifiable example you'll be much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @jodag. I modified the code using `nn.functional.cross_entropy`, still got the memory error. Also, I edited the code to include `make_weight_map` function.

Answer (score 2):

Your `final_train_loader` provides you with an input image `data` and the expected pixel-wise labeling `target`. I assume (following pytorch's conventions) that `data` is of shape B-3-H-W and of `dtype=torch.float`.
More importantly, `target` is of shape B-H-W and of `dtype=torch.long`.

On the other hand `make_weight_map` expects its input to be C-H-W (with `C` = number of classes, NOT batch size), of type numpy array.

Try providing `make_weight_map` the input mask *as it expects it* and see if you get similar errors.
I also recommend that you *visualize* the resulting weight map - to make sure your function does what you expect it to do.

Comment: got your point, I have a doubt, this custom weight map was designed for binary mask images, and number of masks in my images are 3 plus background, will the same equations be applicable to my case too?

Comment: @Mark you can convert your masks to several binary mask (one per label) and apply the same function

Comment: I just edited the code as you asked me to. It's still not working.